# FileObserver for transfer events

Tags: android, filesystems, fileobserver

I have a directory to which user may transfer files from another device. I have a FileObserver watching that directory. But I don’t know what to watch for. I need to know when the file has finished transferring so I can move it to another location. So what event code do I watch for? `FileObserver.CREATE | FileObserver.MODIFY` don’t seem to do it.

**UPDATE**

Based on some logging I make the following observations: for each new file that is transferred to the directory, I get the following events:

```
FileObserver.MOVED_TO : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.OPEN : DSC_0058.JPG
FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE : DSC_0058.JPG
```

So after each move I see a series of OPEN then CLOSE_NOWRITE. I am not sure of the importance of the OPEN then CLOSE_NOWRITE events.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [CLOSE_WRITE](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html#CLOSE_WRITE), because the thing doing the downloading will have to be writing and eventually close the file. That said, there is no guarantee that the writer will not close the file before it's complete (it could reopen and append more).  So be sure to test it to your satisfaction.

Comment: Like it said, it's possible that the downloader can reopen and append more data to the file, which is exactly what you're seeing.  If this is how it behaves, then you can never know when it's 100% done using FileObserver.

Comment: Actually I don't think it adds more to it as it is using `CLOSE_NOWRITE` after each `OPEN`. Doesn't `CLOSE_NOWRITE` mean close without writing anything to it?

Comment: `CLOSE_NOWRITE` means something closed an open file that was only open for reading in the first place.  It had never intended to write data.  We still don't know what the thing is that's doing this (it could be your code!).

Comment: It's not my code as I make sure for troubleshooting I do no interaction with the directory except for calling startWatching the directory. If `startWatching` itself has side effects then it's not my particular usage but the system itself.

Comment: So again, when a file is transferred that pattern is seen: so if I choose to transfer 4 files at once, the pattern is repeated for each file sequentially.